# How to release memory when activity goes to stack?

Tags: android, memory-management, back-stack

My application consist (for example) of 3 activity: Activity1, Activity2, Activity3. Every activity has a unique background image on all its main layout declared in an XML File. 
From Activity1 user goes to Activity2 and next to Activity3 so first 2 get pushed into the stack. 
The problem is that first 2 activities occupy too much memory, and in Activity3 I have OOM exception sometimes.
I have found this answer about reason of this behavior - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836241/1159507 
Before this, I believed that when activity goes to stack it releases all memory. 
I believe that the same behavior with fragments stack.
So my question is - how to relese memory when activity or fragment goes to stack and keep responsible UI on back press?

Comment: Try using `finish()` after `startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: If I call `finish()` I could not return to this activity in future by back pressing.

Comment: If he uses `finish()`, the activity will be destroyed. Then again he'll have to pass intent from `onBackPressed()` of 2nd and 3rd activity. It can be achieved this way but it's bad practice to implement in this way as you are changing Android's default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity's resources (which are not released in onPause, onStop, ...) do not get released when the Activity goes to the background.

- You can remove the background in onPause(), this way the GC will
  be able to destroy it. However, the "empty background" will be there
  for a fraction of a second. It is important to mention, you have to
  do this in onPause(). (I think changes after onPause (like changes in onStop) take effect when the Activity comes to the foreground, so the reference to the background would still be hold by the Activity while it is in the background.)
- Other way is to call finish(), and manage the stack yourself. You
  would have to remember the starting Activity, and navigate to it
  manually when the user presses the back button.
- And the last solution that pops into my mind is to make every Activity that contains huge resources a separate process by declaring the android:process attribute in the manifest. This way all of your Activities would have a separate full sized heap to use.

Comment: >>>It is important to mention, you have to do this in onPause(), because that is the latest point when you can touch the UI<<<
I belive it's better to do in onStop(), becouse it's called after onPause() and you still can  touch the UI, and resore in onStart()

Comment: also when startActivity, acording to the test, methods will be called in next order: Activity1_onPause, Activity2_onCreate, Activity2_onStart, Activity2_onResume, Activity1_onStop

Comment: As I said you cannot touch the UI in onStop. You can try it:)

Comment: I tried and it works pretty well. I mean getBackground() and setBackgroundResource(0)

Comment: Well, I was wrong, you can still manipulate the UI in onStop. However, I have a fear that the Activity would still hold the reference to the background this way. Can you verify that?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I call setBackgroundResource(0) in onPause() memory is released but if onStop() - not released. Do you have an explanation of this?

Comment: I'm not quiet sure, but I think the UI event loop is stopped after onPause (no need for it, since the Activity is not visible after this), so the changes won't take effect until the Activity becomes to the foreground again.

Comment: Okay, so I have a user constantly switching between activities, meaning they may have switched 15 activities in 20 seconds. Could that be a cause of an out of memory error? What should I do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can save all your huge memory consuming objects (Ex: Large Images in your case) to local storage in `onStop()` of your first activity and when user presses back you can load them in `onStart()` of your first activity.

Comment: How to release memory of image if I set in in XML, like "android:background="@drawable/some_image" for my root layout?

Comment: Actually I see the one way - put image manually in `onStart()` and somehow remove it `onStop()` from background. But it pretty unconvinient and unobvious, also I will not see my image in xml IDE preview if I remove this code from XML, or will do the same work twice if not remove from XML.

Comment: @anber The below mentioned link will clear all your doubts. If you still have any doubts get back to me. 
http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: Okay, so I have a user constantly switching between activities, meaning they may have switched 15 activities in 20 seconds. Could that be a cause of an out of memory error? What should I do to fix it? Thanks!